# Optionally exclude certain partitions using OLA's scripts

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, insert, sql-server-2017, ola-hallengren

I have been using OLA's scripts for a long time and love them.

I have a very large database - 20+ TB with hundreds of partitioned tables.

I purge old data by dropping (merging the old partitions).

It is partitioned by date with weekly partitions going back about 6 months.  I have to run daily index maintenance by partition to have any hope of keeping caught up (actually never catch up).

I am now on SQL 2017 and am trying ONLINE Rebuilds by Partition using the *Resumable* option.

What I find is every day I am rebuilding the current partition in almost every table only as it is always fragmented and likely will be fragmented tomorrow again due to massive # of inserts.

What I would like to do is exclude this partition.

This is the partition the current date falls in.

Ie, I would like to only rebuild past partitions.

Having this as an option would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Having this as an option would be very helpful.

[Ola's scripts](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution) are now on github and a [Feature request](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/109) is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the table from OLA and do it as a separate step reindex the problematic segment.

```
/*https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1914/sql-server-database-partitioning-myths-and-truths/ */

-- to return fragmentation information on partitioned indexes
SELECT
 object_name(a.object_id) AS object_name,
 a.index_id,
 b.name,
 b.type_desc,
 a.partition_number,
 a.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED') a
JOIN sys.indexes b on a.object_id = b.object_id and a.index_id = b.index_id
order by object_name(a.object_id), a.index_id, b.name, b.type_desc, a.partition_number


--Rebuild only partition 11.
ALTER INDEX IX_alert_events_timestamp
ON dbo.alert_events
REBUILD Partition = 11;
GO
```

Comment: Since I have over 500 Tables this is not feasible.  And OLA's scripts do rebuild the partitions.  I just want the ability to exclude current.